# Using srun : how to set number of nodes and cores

Tags: parallel-processing, cpu, slurm, cpu-cores

I am new to using commands like srun.
I want to launch a parallel job using 1 node 1cpu and 16 cores, but i dont know what i should indicate when using srun function. (1 node is composed of 2 CPUs with 18 cores on each CPU)

Does anyone knows which parameters i should use?

Answer (score 0):

To set minimums on the cpu resources lower than those available per node, you need to provide `--cpus-per-task` in your `srun` command (see https://slurm.schedmd.com/srun.html#OPT_cpus-per-task).

If you want to explicitly reserve the other 2 cores per cpu for system use, see https://slurm.schedmd.com/mc_support.html#srun_hints for usage of `--cpu-bind` or high level resource limits.